# Swift - How to change a png tint color without losing the clear background?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I've tried the following code and it works. It adds a tint color to my png image but the clear background turns black. The image has details like a shadow or so, so I don't use the normal renderImageAsTemplate property.

```
extension UIImage {
    public func tintImage(with fillColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        return modifiedImage { context, rect in
            // draw black background - workaround to preserve color of partially transparent pixels
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            UIColor.black.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            // draw original image
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            context.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)

            // tint image (losing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
            context.setBlendMode(.color)
            fillColor.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            // mask by alpha values of original image
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            context.draw(context.makeImage()!, in: rect)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func modifiedImage(_ draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ()) -> UIImage {
        // using scale correctly preserves retina images
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        assert(context != nil)

        // correctly rotate image
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        draw(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change the image tint color while maintaining the clear background of the PNG?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652778/fill-uiimage-with-uicolor/39653834#39653834

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. The second extension of the accepted answer worked like a charm :]